# How to apply hyperlink depending upon the details fetched from the API In Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Project and it that I have the contact page which is fetching the details from the API. I want to apply the hyperlink according to the details fetched like if it is a mobile number then `tel` is applied and for the email `mailto` is applied.

This is my **contact.html**:

```
<ion-content padding overflow-scroll="true">
  <ion-grid align-items-center justify-content-center>
    <ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center>
      <ion-col class="mycol22" col-12 *ngFor="let contdetails of this.detailscontact">
          <h3 class="myneh31">{{contdetails?.sub_head}}</h3>
          <hr />
          <a href="tel or mailto"><p class="newmyp2">{{contdetails?.sub_content_first}}</p></a>
          <a href="tel or mailto"><p class="newmyp2">{{contdetails?.sub_content_second}}</p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

The problem is that, How to decide whether to apply tel or mailto depending on the value fetched. This is my output according to the details fetched from the API. Now, I want to apply hyperlink depending upon the details fetched from the API. For **Email**: `mailto` will apply and for **Mobile Number**: `tel` will be applied.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to check if data is email type or not. Use this function as a email validator.

```
emailValidator(email:string): boolean {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

And in your html page

```
<a href="{{emailValidator(email) == true ? 'mailto' || 'tel'}}"></a>
```

To make yourself easy you can return string from emailValidator function:

```
emailValidator(email:string): string {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)) {
        return 'mailto';
    }
    return 'tel'; 
}
```

and in HTML you can use

```
<a href="{{emailValidator(email)}}"></a>
```

Comment: What if, text fetched is simple and I don't want to apply any link.

Comment: Do you mean what if you dont want to keep 'tel or mailto' in html and do it from your component?

Comment: LIke if the text is not email or mobile number then?

Comment: You have to add another condition in HTML or emailValidator function

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*ngIf should come handy:

```
  <a href="tel" *ngIf="condition">...</a> // or any boolean as condition
  <a href="mailto" *ngIf="!condition">...</a>  // or any other condition
```

Comment: If you need further help for the condition, give the data extract please

Comment: Extract data is email and mobile number as mentioned in the image.

Comment: but how to apply mailto and tel on the tag because it is fetching the details from the API.

Comment: Like this: <a href="tel or mailto">

Comment: [attr.href]="mailto"

Comment: How I will check that the value fetched from the API is email or mobile number?

Comment: You can use a regEx to check if it's a valid email or all numbers. Put it in a method (for example mymethod()) that return the that value to [href] or [attr.href]="myMethod()"